# Fill Excel cells with random numbers

Tags: python, excel, random, list-comprehension, xlsxwriter

I have a question about how to fill some cells in Excels with random values? For example,
I have a part of the code with:

```
numbers_random = (random.random() for _ in range(10))
worksheet.write('A1:J1', numbers_random)
```

Which gave me the error of:
TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'generator'> in write()

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write multiple cells, use `write_row()` or `write_column()` as shown in the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html).

Also, try changing the first line to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) (using square brackets instead of parentheses):

```
 numbers_random = [random.random() for _ in range(10)]
```